# Django - queryset vs model in Generic View

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset, django-generic-views

I'm pretty new at Django and wondering what is the difference between defining model vs queryset in a generic view like ListView.  Here's my code example in my urls.py file for the project:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(
    model=Person,
    context_object_name='people',
    template_name='index.html', 
    )),
)
```

I've also used the same this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(
    queryset=Person.objects.all,
    context_object_name='people',
    template_name='index.html', 
    )),
)
```

And received the same result on my view.  I'm assuming there are different things you can do with a queryset?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using `model=Person` or `queryset=Person.objects.all` give the same result.

Let's look at the code. A `ListView` has the following method:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    """
    Get the list of items for this view. This must be an interable, and may
    be a queryset (in which qs-specific behavior will be enabled).
    """
    if self.queryset is not None:
        queryset = self.queryset
        if hasattr(queryset, '_clone'):
            queryset = queryset._clone()
    elif self.model is not None:
        queryset = self.model._default_manager.all()
    else:
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(u"'%s' must define 'queryset' or 'model'"
                                   % self.__class__.__name__)
    return queryset
```

As you can see, it first looks for `self.queryset` and, if that does not exist, for `self.model`. So there are two possibilities to specify a list: you can provide a queryset yourself or you can specify a model class (in which case Django will call the `all()` method of the default manager, which is `objects`).

> I'm assuming there are different things you can do with a queryset?

Yes. If you specify a `model`, then you get all instances by default. But if you specify a `queryset`, you can also call other methods of a model manager, such as `Person.objects.children()` which could return only persons with `age <= 12`.